# How to install multiple wordpress site on localhost

Tags: installation, localhost

I am trying to install a third wordpress installation on my localhost. I used xampp to install the first. I access it by using the URL localhost/wordpress. Then I installed a second site at C:\xampp\apps\plcoa and accessed it with the URL localhost/plcoa. I swear that all that I did was create the above directory and install all of Wordpress's folders and files in that folder. Then I ran localhost/plcoa/wp-admin/install.php. It was easy. Now, I want to add a third site. I installed WP just like before at C:\xampp\apps\golf. When I try to set up with the URL localhost/golf/wp-admin/install.php I get the message "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Can someone help me - please.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be simple. All that I had to do was to edit the "Apache (httpd-xampp.config)" file. Accessed it from the xampp control panel. Then added this code.

```
Alias /golf "C:\xampp\apps\golf"
<Directory "C:\xampp\apps\golf" >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```